# What are the new features in Angular2 which are not in previous versions?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have seen many articles regarding the changes in `Angular2` . But I can't find much  advantage in using `Angular2`. Can some one point out some new things that can be done using `Angular2` which can't be done using the previous versions.

I know there are changes like `$scope` changed to `this`. I'm not asking for changes. I'm asking for new features that is in `Angular2`.

Comment: Just [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=Angular2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=Angularjs+2.0+new+features) found http://www.sitepoint.com/whats-new-in-angularjs-2/ and http://ng-learn.org/2014/03/AngularJS-2-Status-Preview/ and many more... articles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the features of the language are available in the language itself or if not simple google will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The TL;DR Version

- Because ES6 is important to pick up, so no need for a custom dependency management system anymore. ES6 and Angular 1 together get ugly fast, as they together introduce a bajillion coding styles :(
- Although the library is overall heavier, the architecture it uses (all component based) is a lot faster, lighter, and modular for a scalable application. See http://info.meteor.com/blog/comparing-performance-of-blaze-react-angular-meteor-and-angular-2-with-meteor
- You receive (upcoming) Server Side Rendering, which enables fast initial load time and Search Engine Optimization (Yay!) See: https://github.com/angular/universal
- You receive WebWorker friendliness, which makes your application able to "multi-task". See: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/docs/web_workers/web_workers.md
- Shadow DOM is not fully inherited by Angular 2 yet, but I'm sure it will be. It has some support right now.
- The whole concept of $scope is gone. You receive two way data binding with anything you put in your ES6/TypeScript class, but anything more you need to create a Observable or promise. Unfortunately, you can't just shove anything into the scope, digest, and WALAH! anymore.
- And of course, all the cool stuff they mention on their website: https://angular.io/features.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: What part related to shadow DOM do you think is missing?

Comment: I could totally be out of date on this one, but last time I read during Alpha Shadow DOM direct native support was only for Chrome

Comment: Ok, in your answer it sounds more like an Angular limitation. No shadow DOM is not yet available in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

- Support for different languages TypeScript, Dart, ES5, ES6.
- Change detection is much more effective
- Support for isomorphic applications where the same code can run on the server, the browser and a WebWorker in the browser
- Moves more work to build time to reduce the time for the initial page load.
- Simplified binding syntax
- Improved DI

There are also lots of mostly smaller and tiny features that Angular2 doesn't (yet?) support which Angular 1.x does.